# schemamigration using south and model field change

Tags: django, migration, django-south

I have a model like this

```
class Task(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   ...

class TaskForm(forms.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
        model = Task
```

Then,I added couple of fields to Task and did migration

> python manage.py schemamigration myapp --initial
>   python manage.py migrate myapp

Migration is successfully done.

Now,as an afterthought,I added a help_text to the model field

```
class Task(models.Model):
       name = models.CharField(max_length=100,help_text='choose a good one')
       ...
```

Do I have to do the schemamigration again?I think his change doesn't affect the database table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need not run migrate again.

Django do not save `help_text` to the databases, `help_text` exists in application level, Django render it to HTML.